# Add custom iOS Build Setting options

Tags: ios, xcode, build, settings, build-settings

I am trying to create a drop down for a custom User-Defined build setting. I have created the setting `LOGGING_LEVEL` but I can only enter a static value against each build configuration

[image]

I want to be able to select from a list like all the pre-defined setting

[image]

I am not sure if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible. User Defined setting is some sort of preprocessed macro. It should hold no more than one value as it's a basic variable.